# Match word not preceded by character

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'd like to match the word STOP as long as it is does not have a ' anywhere before it - so:

`STOP    'something` - is legal

but `' STOP` - isn't 
and neither is `something ' something else STOP`

I've tried using negative lookahead but I can't use quantifiers to allow unlimited whitespace / words

Comment: What regex flavor it is?

Comment: It's in Atom text editor - I'm guessing it's the same as whatever Chromium supports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to match it without any capturing, I guess something simple as
`^[^']*STOP` 
does the trick.